# HTML tags in views field label. Is it possible?

Tags: views, 8, theming

By default in views field label it possible to put only plain text, so the markup looks like:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-price">
  <span class="views-label views-label-price">Price: -10%</span>
  <span class="field-content">9.99</span>
</div>
```

But I need to add some text wrapped with tags, like

```
<div class="views-field views-field-price">
  <span class="views-label views-label-price">Price: <span>-10%</span></span>
  <span class="field-content">9.99</span>
</div>
```

How it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck create label

Click on rewrite results, check mark override out and put:

```
  <span class="views-label views-label-price">Price: <span>-10%</span></span>
  <span class="field-content">{{ field_price }}</span>
```

I'm not 100% that it's `{{ field_price }}`, but you can click on replacement patterns to see the pattern name.

[image]

Comment: As a result, I did not have to do this task. But the advice is correct. Someone it could be useful!